# Print contents of register to console in LC3 Assembly

Tags: assembly, lc3

Say I have a value (eg. 1234) that I load into R0. How could I print this value to the console?

Comment: Consult the manual for the simulator/emulator you're using to see if there is any routine you can call to print integers. Otherwise, see if there is any routine to print strings. In that case you'll have to convert your integer into a string first.

Comment: I can use PUTS to print a string that starts at the value stored in R0. In that case how can I convert my value into a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you would like to print a number out to the console but you're getting random characters if anything.

This happens when the LC3 tries to interpret your number as an ASCII character. Example: The number 8 in ASCII is the backspace character.

To make your program work you will need to add **48 (decimal)** or **x30 (hex)** to your number before you can print it to the console.

```
.ORIG x3000
  AND R0, R0, #0    ; Clear R0
  LD R0, NUM        ; load our number into R0
  LD R2, ASCII      ; load the ascii offset into R2
  ADD R0, R0, R2    
  OUT
HALT                ; Trap x25

NUM   .fill  x02    ; Our Number to print
ASCII .fill  x30    ; Our ASCII offset
.END
```

---

In your example you want to print off an array of characters like 1234. The concept for this is pretty similar but we'll need to work with pointers and a for loop.

```
.ORIG x3000
  AND R0, R0, #0    ; Clear R0
  AND R1, R1, #0    ; Clear R1
  AND R3, R3, #0    ; Clear R3
  LEA R0, NUM       ; pointer [mem]NUM
  ADD R1, R1, R0    ; Store the pointer address of R0 into R1
  LD R2, ASCII      ; load the ascii offset into R2

FOR_LOOP
  LDR R4, R1, #0    ; load the contents of mem address of R1 into R4
  BRz END_LOOP
  ADD R4, R4, R2    ; Add our number to the ASCII offset
  STR R4, R1, #0    ; Store the new value in R4 into [mem] address R1
  ADD R1, R1, #1    ; move our memory pointer down one
  BRnzp FOR_LOOP    ; loop again until we get an x00 char
END_LOOP

  PUTs              ; print our string starting from [mem]address in R0
HALT                ; Trap x25

ASCII .fill  x30    ; Our ASCII offset
NUM   .fill  x01    ; Our Number to print
      .fill  x02     
      .fill  x03
      .fill  x04
.END
```

Comment: This only works if you're using unpacked BCD to store your number.  It doesn't help if you have a binary integer like 123 in a single register (or byte memory location).