# Print long numbers to console in LC3 Assembly

Tags: assembly, output, out, lc3

say that I have a number(for example any number between 1 and 10^6) I don't know how many digit are in this number and it stored in R0 ... so How could I print this value to the console?

Comment: LC-3 registers are 16-bit, right? That limits the range of number you can store in R0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print contents of register to console in LC3 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401318/print-contents-of-register-to-console-in-lc3-assembly)

Comment: right.. but what if you have for example 1234 in decimal and you want to print it to the console..
@RuudHelderman